# How to pass object through Web client call to a web API controller that expects object as parameter?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have console app as client and am trying to get worksheet data by passing client Id to a web API controller.Then creating a ClientWorkSheet object with received info from previous API call plus some other details. (Code working fine until this point)

Now I want to pass this ClientWorkSheet object as parameter to another API controller that takes the object and prints it out. I am getting media-type not supported error at this pointcall To API:
[image: call To API]. Controller action method:
[image: Controller action method]

Here is the WebClient Code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
        client.Headers.Add("Origin:http://localhost:50920");
        client.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow- 
        Origin:http://localhost:9000");
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}
```

Comment: Logically if the webapi uses json.net to *deserialize* and object, then you would use json.net to *serialize* the object...  at least that is probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Did not understand your comment. Are you saying that I should deserialize the object in the action method? If yes, then what should the input parameter type be instead of object? Have added controller code img too for reference. Pls help

Comment: I won't be looking at your controller code, please provide the **actual code** not a screen shot.  Also, only add the actual web api method that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues suggested the use of RestSharp to pass objects in Web API call and it worked for me. Sharing as it is pretty simple to use.

`var reportRequest = new RestSharp.RestRequest("api/ClientWorksheet/CreateClientWorksheetAsPdf", RestSharp.Method.POST)`

```
            {
                RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json
            };

            reportRequest.AddBody(sheet);
            var restClient = new RestSharp.RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:50061"),
                Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.NtlmAuthenticator()
            };

                var response = restClient.Execute<DataSet>(reportRequest);
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //success
                }
```